# Merge multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to know how can I merge all columns that start with same name into one as mean of them all OR sum.

Ex:

```
           Over_100         Over_200        Over_300_et
1             10                50               60
```

would give

```
           Overs_mean 
1              40
```

Or:

```
           Overs_sum 
1              120
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example

```
df.filter(like='Over').mean(1)

1    40.0
dtype: float64
```

To make a dataframe

```
df.filter(like='Over').mean(1).to_frame('Overs_mean')

   Overs_mean
1        40.0
```

---

For a more complete solution, use `groupby`.
Consider the dataframe `df` constructed below:

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3))).add_prefix('A_')
d2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3))).add_prefix('B_')
d3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3))).add_prefix('C_')

df = pd.concat([d1, d2, d3], axis=1)

print(df)
```

We'll group by columns that start with the same thing up to the first underscore.

```
means = df.groupby(
    df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1
).mean().add_suffix('_mean')
print(means)

     A_mean    B_mean    C_mean
0  3.000000  4.000000  7.000000
1  6.000000  3.333333  5.666667
2  4.666667  6.666667  4.666667
3  2.666667  4.000000  5.000000
4  4.333333  7.000000  6.666667
```

---

To take only those columns that start with `A` and combine it back with the rest:

```
a_cols = df.columns.str.startswith('A')

df.loc[:, ~a_cols].join(df.loc[:, a_cols].mean(1).rename('A_mean'))

   B_0  B_1  B_2  C_0  C_1  C_2    A_mean
0    7    3    2    8    7    6  3.000000
1    4    3    3    4    7    6  6.000000
2    6    7    7    2    6    6  4.666667
3    4    5    3    5    2    8  2.666667
4    7    5    9    7    5    8  4.333333
```

Comment: like='over' behave like contains ?

Comment: @hdatas more like starts with.

Comment: I am not able to keep the other columns that don't start with over